# Process output of arbitrary number of goroutines as they finish

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, web-crawler, goroutine

WaitGroups are used to *wait* for all goroutines to finish before continuing execution, but how do you process their outputs as they finish?

This method works okay

```
c := make(chan string)
rc := 0
for _, url := range urls {
    rc++
    go func(url string) {
        data := get(url)
        c <- data
    }(url)
}
for i := 0; i < rc; i++ {
    data <- c
}
```

It stops working okay however when you have to call goroutines from goroutines

```
for _, url := range urls {
    go func(url string) {
        data := get(url)
        urls := get_urls(data)
        for _, url := range urls {
            go func(url){
                data := get(url)
                c <- data
            }(url)
        }
    }(url)
}
```

This time we will have to put `rc++` inside of goroutine which will result in undefined behavior. What do?

Comment: Don't count. Range on the channel & let your manager goroutine close the channel when the workers are done. The results channel range will then naturally exit as all results have been received.

Comment: @colm.anseo How is manager goroutine supposed to know that?

Comment: Via a `sync.WaitGroup`

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to solve this, but the most idiomatic (thus probably "best") is as [colm.anseo suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147764/process-output-of-arbitrary-number-of-goroutines-as-they-finish#comment122213554_69147764): have the "process output" routine use a ranged for loop, and have the generating routines use a `sync.WaitGroup` counter with a closing goroutine, like this:

```
// result channel:
c := make(chan string)

// wait-group:
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// run over the URLs
for _, url := range urls {
    wg.Add(1) // count up another start()
    go start(&wg, url, c)
}
go func() {
    // wait for all start()s to say they are done
    wg.Wait()
    // and now close c
    close(c)
}()
for data := range c {
    // deal with data
}
```

Now we can see how each `start` function works:

```
// start() loads up a set of URLs from a URL,
// then spins off worker goroutines that read from
// each of those URLs, sending data to channel c.
// When all of its subsidiary goroutines have finished,
// start() signals that it is done.
func start(wg *sync.Waitgroup, url string, c chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    data := get(url)
    urls := get_urls(data)
    var subWG sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        subWG.Add(1)
        go func(url) {
            defer subWG.Done()
            data := get(url)
            c <- data
        }(url)
    }
    subWG.Wait()
}
```

Function `start` can of course be inlined, as you did originally; I wrote it this way for clarity.

(In general, rather than spinning off some mystery number of goroutines per URL, you really want a "limited number of workers" pattern here, i.e., a *worker pool*.  There are lots of examples of this on the web.)

Comment: Yes, *limiting* the number of workers is indeed necessary to avoid too many connections and panic, but the exact number of them can't be known until the data from `url` is received.

Comment: Yes, but with the worker-pool system, you gather work and distribute it into the worker pool with automatic backpressure *from* the worker pool so that you keep a steady(ish) pipeline flowing.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an indeterminate number of results - its best to let the workers and the worker manager goroutine manage the results channel and close it when all results are complete. This avoid messy counting/mutex logic.

So to convert your first example:

```
c := make(chan string)

var wg sync.WaitGroup // used by manager goroutine to determine finish

for _, url := range urls {
    wg.Add(1) // about to start worker
    go func(url string) {
        defer wg.Done() // worker is complete
        data := get(url)
        c <- data
    }(url)
}

// manager goroutine
go func() {
    wg.Wait() // all workers are done ...
    close(c) // ... so signal this via channel close
}()

// results collection is then very simple
for data := range c {
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

This design applies identically to your situation where the workers create more goroutines. But as @torek noted an extra `sync.WaitGroup` is needed:

```
c := make(chan string)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

for _, url := range urls {
    wg.Add(1) // new worker
    go func(url string) {
        defer wg.Done() // worker done
        data := get(url)
        urls := get_urls(data)
        var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
        for _, url := range urls {
            wg2.Add(1)
            go func(url) {
                defer wg2.Done()
                data := get(url)
                c <- data
            }(url)
        }
        wg2.Wait()
    }(url)
}

// manager goroutine
go func() {
    wg.Wait() // all workers are done ...
    close(c)  // ... so signal this via channel close
}()

for data := range c {
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Comment: You did the same thing I did the first time, forgetting to have a sub-wait-group. Alternatively of course we can just do extra `wg.Add(1)` and `defer wg.Done()` calls in the sub-go-routines, using a single overall waitgroup counter.

Comment: Why do the workers have to be added to a new wait group?

Comment: Because we need to track their lifecycle too. For a worker to be considered complete, we need to know it's sub-workers are complete. Then once all the workers are complete, we can with certainty close the results channel. (Closing the channel too early, would cause a panic with a write on a closed channel.)